# Need xpath to find value in a table from another value in the same row

Tags: html, ruby, xpath, capybara

I need to return the value of a td, if another td in that row matches my search query. Specifically, I have the 'name' attribute and I want to return the 'id' attribute (found in the same row). Here is a sample of the HTML:

```
<tr class='desired_row'>
  <td>
    <input id="bulk_ids_" name="bulk_ids[]" type="checkbox" value="50" />
  </td>
  <td class='id_field integer_type' title='50'>50</td>
  <td class='logo_field carrierwave_type' title=''></td>
  <td class='name_field string_type' title='Test'>Test</td>
  <td class='created_at_field datetime_type' title='January 22, 2015 23:11'>January 22, 2015 23:11</td>
  <td class='updated_at_field datetime_type' title='January 22, 2015 23:11'>January 22, 2015 23:11</td>
  <td class='address_1_field string_type' title='1600 Pennsylvania Ave'>1600 Pennsylvania Ave</td> 
</tr>
```

So I want to input 'Test' into my query and have it return 50. Here is my failing query:

```
find(:xpath, "//tr[td/@title = 'Test']") do |row|
  id = find(:xpath, "//td[@class = 'id_field integer_type']./@title")
  return id
end

=> #<Capybara::Element tag="tr">
```

So it is correctly returning a Capybara row, but the query is not finding the ID. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath expression is incorrect. There cannot be `.` immediately after `]`.

```
id = find(:xpath, "//td[@class = 'id_field integer_type']/@title")
```

If that does not help, try both

```
id = find(:xpath, "td[@class = 'id_field integer_type']/@title")
```

and

```
id = find(:xpath, ".//td[@class = 'id_field integer_type']/@title")
```

You might even have to do

```
id = find(:xpath, "string(//td[@class = 'id_field integer_type']/@title)")
```

depending on the behaviour of your XPath environment.

Comment: I'm still getting the same return Capybara element. I'm thinking it may have to do with the first query. I'd assume that the Capybara node would have more information that the HTML tag "tr"?

Comment: @DrewB If you tried everything I suggested, we really have to wait for someone who knows Capybara. Actually, why not use `//tr[td/@title = 'Test']/td[@class = 'id_field integer_type']/@title`? Do you need that row?